# Changing configuration at runtime for PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I was trying to deploy a trained Faiss index to PySpark and do a distributed search. So the whole process includes:

1. Pre-process
2. Load Faiss Index(~15G) and do Faiss Search
3. Post-process and write to HDFS

I set CPUs per task as 10 (`spark.task.cpus=10`) in order to do multi-thread search. But step 1 and step 3 can only utilize 1 CPU per task. In order to utilize all CPUs I want to set `spark.task.cpus=1` before step 1 and 3. I have tried set method of `RuntimeConfig` but it seems it made my program stuck. Any advice on how to change config at runtime or how to optimize this problem?

Code example:

```py
def load_and_search(x, model_path):
    faiss_idx = faiss.read_index(model_path)
    q_vec = np.concatenate(x)
    _, idx_array = faiss_idx.search(q_vec, k=10)
    return idx_array


data = sc.textFile(input_path)

# preprocess, only used one cpu per task
data = data.map(lambda x: x)

# load faiss index and search, used multiple cpus per task
data = data.mapPartitioins(lambda x: load_and_search(x, model_path))

# postprocess and write, one cpu per task
data = data.map(lambda x: x).saveAsTextFile(result_path)
```

Comment: Can you give a more specific code example of what you are trying to do so that it will be easier to help you with optimization?

Comment: @user3689574 Thanks for you comment. Example added.

Comment: what is `load_and_search ` doing this is not a Spark code right?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative idea: use [`mapPartitions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.mapPartitions) for steps 1 and 3. Then, use a multiprocessing pool within each worker to map the items in the partition in parallel. This way, you can use all cpus assigned to a worker without changing configuration (which I do not know if it is at all possible).

Pseudocode:

```
def item_mapper(item):
    return ...

def partition_mapper(partition):
    with mp.Pool(processes=10) as pool:
        yield from pool.imap(item_mapper, partition)

rdd.mapPartitions(partition_mapper)
```

Comment: Modifying configuration at runtime isn't supported.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can change the sparkContext properties in the following ways:

```
conf = sc._conf.setAll([('spark.task.cpus','1')])
sc._conf.getAll()
data = data.map(lambda x: x)

conf = sc._conf.setAll([('spark.task.cpus','10')])
sc._conf.getAll()
# load faiss index and search, used multiple cpus per task
data = data.mapPartitioins(lambda x: load_and_search(x, model_path))

conf = sc._conf.setAll([('spark.task.cpus','1')])
sc._conf.getAll()
# postprocess and write, one cpu per task
data = data.map(lambda x: x).saveAsTextFile(result_path)
```

getAll() can be removed, added just to check the current configuration.

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: I have tested the setup of conf variable and it works.

Comment: Alright setting the variable works, but is the parallelism actually changed when you execute the code?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late. Instead of mapPartition, I used pandas_udf and broadcast-repartition to perform distributed search.

```
k = 10

# Enable Arrow support.
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.maxRecordsPerBatch", "64")

# Load index and broadcast to available workers
index = faiss.read_index("path_to_index)
bc_index = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(index)

# Define pandas_Udf to perform search
@spark_fn.pandas_udf(
            returnType=ArrayType(FloatType()),
            functionType=spark_fn.PandasUDFType.SCALAR,
)
def load_and_search(query_vectors):
            import pandas as pd
            import numpy as np
            # Cast to numpy
            query_vectors = np.asarray(query_vectors.to_list())
            #query_vectors = np.concatenate(queries)
            _, index_arr = bc_index.value.search(query_vectors, k=k)
            return pd.Series(index_arr.tolist())

# Repartition queries and perform search
queries = queries.coalesce(numPartitions)
queries = queries.withColumn("output", load_and_search(spark_fn.col("vector_col)))
```